# not assignable to type '() => void' error when using React useMemo() with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

I have a very simple react app with typescript.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { Editor as Draft, EditorState } from "draft-js";

const Editor: React.FC = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState<() => EditorState>(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  const handleEditorChange = useMemo(
    (nextEditorState: EditorState) => setEditorState(nextEditorState),
    [editorState]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Draft editorState={editorState} onChange={handleEditorChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

I'm trying to get it to work using `useMemo()` but when I wrap `handleEditorChange` in `useMemo` I get the following error:

```
argument of type '(nextEditorState: EditorState) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'
```

How to correctly use TypeScript here and get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2):

[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) is used to memoize the **return** value of the function provided to it but you are using it as an onChange handler.

So remove it and just use the function as the handler

```
const handleEditorChange = (nextEditorState: EditorState) => 
  setEditorState(nextEditorState)
```

Second, you type your state as a function that returns the `EditorState` which is not correct, you want the type to be `EditorState`.

TypeScript can also infer the type so you don't even need to type it

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty())
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript requires that `useMemo` has an explicit `return`.

```
export function useHello(): string {
    return useMemo<string>(() => {
        return 'hello';
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `useCallback()` in this situation.